# Double free in Google Mock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I'm a newbie in Google Test and Mock framework.

I just try to run "Turtle" example, it was successful.

However, error message was displayed : double free or corruption (!prev).

**MockTurtle.h**

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

class MockTurtle : class Turtle {
    MOCK_METHOD0(PenUp, void());
    MOCK_METHOD0(PenDown, void());
    MOCK_METHOD1(Forward, void(int distance));
    MOCK_METHOD1(Turn, void(int degrees));
    MOCK_METHOD2(GoTo, void(int x, int y));
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(GetX, int());
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(GetY, int());
};
```

**Turtle.h**

```
class Turtle {
    virtual ~Turtle() {}
    virtual void PenUp() = 0;
    virtual void PenDown() = 0;
    virtual void Forward(int distance) = 0;
    virtual void Turn(int degrees) = 0;
    virtual void GoTo(int x, int y) = 0;
    virtual int GetX() const = 0;
    virtual int GetY() const = 0;
};
```

**Painter.h**

```
class Painter    
{
       Turtle* turtle;
public:
       Painter( Turtle* turtle )
               :       turtle(turtle){}

       bool DrawCircle(int, int, int){
               turtle->PenDown();
               return true;
       }
};
```

**Main_test.cpp**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include "Painter.h"
#include "MockTurtle.h"

using ::testing::AtLeast;

TEST(PainterTest, CanDrawSomething) {
 MockTurtle turtle;
 EXPECT_CALL(turtle, PenDown())
     .Times(AtLeast(1));

 Painter painter(&turtle);

 EXPECT_TRUE(painter.DrawCircle(0, 0, 10));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 // The following line must be executed to initialize Google Mock
 // (and Google Test) before running the tests.
 ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
 return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

**Result**

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.    
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from PainterTest
[ RUN      ] PainterTest.CanDrawSomething
[       OK ] PainterTest.CanDrawSomething (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from PainterTest (0 ms total)
[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
*** Error in `/home/user/workspace/google_mock_2/Debug/google_mock_2': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x098a8080 ***
```

I tried to google, saw several same problems. People said that should not use mock as global variable.

But my example did not use global variable.

Please help me explain why double free happen.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I already add more source code. That is all in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time, I built google test and google mock in SHARED library.
And error (double free) happened.

I have tried to build as STATIC library. This error no longer appear.
I don't know why but I will investigate to know more detail.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. In my case, the problem was to be linking both google test and google mock. I solved the problem by just linking gmock, no gtest.

I think this occurs because, as far as I understand, gmock already links statically gtest: When you compile gmock as a dynamic library, gtest is generated as well (as a static library) in the same folder where gmock is built. I suppose gmock depends on, and uses, this library.

I suppose that, in some way, linking gtest twice (both statically and dynamically), produces a free() to be executed twice.

Answer (score 2):

For your information, this was a bug in gtest/gmock for CMake shared libraries build. It has already been resolved with [this pull request](https://github.com/google/googletest/pull/1339). For more details read the discussion in [issue 930](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/930).

Answer (score 1):

Your error is somewhere you're not showing us.  I managed to add sufficient headers and definitions to get your example to compile:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

class Turtle {
public:
    virtual ~Turtle() = default;
    virtual void PenDown() = 0;
};

class MockTurtle : public Turtle {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(PenDown, void());
};


class Painter
{
    Turtle *turtle;

public:
    Painter(Turtle *turtle)
        : turtle(turtle)
    {}

    bool DrawCircle(int, int, int)
    {
        turtle->PenDown();
        return true;
    }
};

TEST(PainterTest, CanDrawSomething)
{
    MockTurtle turtle;
    EXPECT_CALL(turtle, PenDown()).Times(testing::AtLeast(1));

    Painter painter(&turtle);
    EXPECT_TRUE(painter.DrawCircle(0, 0, 10));
}
```

using this makefile:

```make
VPATH += $(GTEST_DIR)/src
VPATH += $(GMOCK_DIR)/src
gtest%.o: CPPFLAGS += -I$(GTEST_DIR)
gmock%.o: CPPFLAGS += -I$(GMOCK_DIR)

40762798: CXXFLAGS += -isystem $(GTEST_DIR)/include -isystem $(GMOCK_DIR)
40762798: CXXFLAGS += -pthread -Wno-effc++
40762798: LDLIBS += -lpthread
40762798: CC=g++
40762798: 40762798.o gtest_main.o gtest-all.o gmock-all.o
```

Then I get no errors, and Valgrind gives a clean bill of health:

```
valgrind  ./40762798 
==24351== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==24351== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==24351== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==24351== Command: ./40762798
==24351== 
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from PainterTest
[ RUN      ] PainterTest.CanDrawSomething
[       OK ] PainterTest.CanDrawSomething (84 ms)
[----------] 1 test from PainterTest (92 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (125 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
==24351== 
==24351== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24351==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24351==   total heap usage: 183 allocs, 183 frees, 117,387 bytes allocated
==24351== 
==24351== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==24351== 
==24351== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==24351== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: I use Eclipse to build my example. I will try to use makefile to build the example.